# keeping content of ui dialog in div after closing dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have `<div id='A'>` in which I have some info `</div>`

then I fire command

```
$('#A').dialog();
```

after doing something I close the dialog

```
$('#A').dialog('close');
```

And it closes with all my info. But I want it to close but my info remain in DIV.

Problem is that while closing, ui dialog also removes the whole div, so there is nothing left after closing.

Comment: It shouldn't delete the div. It will append it to the body and remove from it's original location but if you run $('#A').dialog('open'); it should open again. Do you have anything else attached to the close event or something else that could be modifying that div?

Comment: I update content of the div via Ajax.

Comment: @Syon you are correct about second dialog.open. I opened it and it opened. But if it is so then why I cannot see it after I close it ????

Comment: try using ctrl+f in your console and look for the id #A

Comment: Is the #A div content visible on the page before you call dialog? If so, are you trying to make it return to its original location? I could be wrong but I don't think that's natively built-in. You'll probably need to save its original location then re-append it using the 'dialogclose' event callback.

Comment: @Syon Div is empty from the beginning, then after getting some info via ajax, I put it into div and at the same moment fire dialog open command. And later when I close dialog the whole info disappears. I even cannot find the div itself using CTR+F on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'close' method does not remove the div as was pointed out, it does set it to 'display:none' and the selector does not work as expected once it is a dialog; At least that is what I found. You can't find it with control+f because it is not displayed. If you look at the page with Firebug or Developer tools, you will see it is still there.

Try this:

```
var theA = $('#A');
theA.dialog();

//do ajax stuff here;

//some where else instead of closing the dialog

theA.dialog('destroy'); //returns the div to its pre-dialog state
theA.css('display','block');
```

I made a fiddle to demonstrate what I did to see if this works. I used a locking flags to make sure I was not 'dialoging' the same time I was closing. but I was able to do what you are talking about in regard to changing the content of the div and then putting it back into the page. I used destroy instead of close to show it going back into the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/jvSb3/3/

in the fiddle I used a text box to change the content of the div while it was in dialog form. then in the close handler, I destroy the dialog and then make it visible again.